# Having following error while creating dynamic query in pdo. "PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number"

Tags: php, pdo

I am facing this error while shifting my code to pdo.>>"PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens"

I am creating query dynamically. Here is my code :

```
           $upquery2= $pdo->prepare('UPDATE contact SET '.$pdoUp.' WHERE 
            Cid=:Cid');
            $upquery2->execute([$upd]);
            $upres = $upquery2->rowCount();
```

Print result of prepared statement is like this:

```
UPDATE contact SET `name=:name,designation=:designation,company=:company,location=:location,phone=:phone,whatsapp=:whatsapp,direct=:direct,text=:text,email=:email,website=:website,chat=:chat,facebook=:facebook,linkedin=:linkedin,skype=:skype,google=:google,notes=:notes WHERE Cid=:Cid`
```

Print result of $upd

```
$upd = ''name'=>'Mahendra Singh Dhoni','designation'=>' Cricketer','company'=>' BCCI','location'=>'India ','phone'=>'+90874387439','whatsapp'=>'89098779','direct'=>'99-9990008','text'=>'903009332','email'=>'msd@msd.com','website'=>'http://www.msd.com/','chat'=>'99999000','facebook'=>'https://web.facebook.com/','linkedin'=>'https://www.linkedin.com','skype'=>'abcd','google'=>'https://plus.google.com/','notes'=>'Mahendra Singh Dhoni is an Indian cricketer.','Cid'=>'28''
```

When i copy and paste the printed values of $upd and $pdoUp directly in my code it works.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare(' UPDATE contact SET name=:name,designation=:designation,company=:company,location=:location,phone=:phone,whatsapp=:whatsapp,direct=:direct,text=:text,email=:email,website=:website,chat=:chat,facebook=:facebook,linkedin=:linkedin,skype=:skype,google=:google,notes=:notes WHERE Cid=:Cid');
$stmt->execute(['name'=>'abcd','designation'=>' xyz','company'=>' zxc','location'=>'India ','phone'=>'+90874387439','whatsapp'=>'89098779','direct'=>'99-9990008','text'=>'903009332','email'=>'msd@msd.com','website'=>'http://www.msd.com/','chat'=>'99999000','facebook'=>'https://web.facebook.com/','linkedin'=>'https://www.linkedin.com','skype'=>'abcd','google'=>'https://plus.google.com/','notes'=>'Mahendra Singh Dhoni is an Indian cricketer.','Cid'=>'28']);
```

Can someone tell me where i am wrong ?

Comment: Instead of string you need to create the array  `$upd =array('name'=>'Mahendra Singh Dhoni','designation'=>' Cricketer',....);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st :** Instead of string you need to create the array

```
$upd =array('name'=>'abcd','designation'=>' xyz','company'=>' zxc','location'=>'India ','phone'=>'+90874387439','whatsapp'=>'89098779','direct'=>'99-9990008','text'=>'903009332','email'=>'msd@msd.com','website'=>'http://www.msd.com/','chat'=>'99999000','facebook'=>'https://web.facebook.com/','linkedin'=>'https://www.linkedin.com','skype'=>'abcd','google'=>'https://plus.google.com/','notes'=>'Mahendra Singh Dhoni is an Indian cricketer.','Cid'=>'28');
```

**2nd :** And pass the parameter like this

```
$upquery2->execute($upd);
```

**Note :** your trying to build a array from string . it's not possible on that way  what you tried .